# Spring Batch Monitoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am having a really tough time with this for some reason and would love some help. All I really need to do it access when Spring Batch is failing and grab the data. I have tried to implement Spring Batch Admin but that didn't seem to work so I was going to write my own class, but I can not seem to get it to work. Anyone have any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ItemListenerSupport`. Override `onRead Error()`,  `onProcessError ()` and `onWriteError()`, etc., methods. For e.g., on error in your writer,
`onWriteError()` method will be invoked and you will get exception and list of objects.

```
public class ItemFailureLoggerListener extends ItemListenerSupport {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog("item.error");

    public void onReadError(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Encountered error on read", e);
    }

    public void onWriteError(Exception ex, Object item) {
        logger.error("Encountered error on write", ex);
    }

}
```

Having implemented this listener it must be registered with the step:

```
<step id="simpleStep">
    ...
    <listeners>
        <listener>
            <bean class="org.example...ItemFailureLoggerListener"/>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</step>
```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html